# How to check allocation unit size on a hard drive on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space, ubuntu-12.04, allocation-unit

How can I check on Ubuntu 12.04 allocation unit size on my hard drives?
Is there any simple way (as a terminal command), I've been searching for this info in Disk Utility, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try :

```
hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

Assuming /dev/sda is the drive you're interested in.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but the allocation unit size (cluster size) information is not in the info displayed after executing `hdparm -I /dev/sdb` (in my case)

Comment: apologies, try : dumpe2fs /dev/sdbX where X is your partition number.  If this works and contains the info you need, its the filesystem allocation size you were after and I'll update my original answer accordingly.  Use "df" to see which devices are mapped to which filesystems.

Comment: this is what I get when run the command  

`dumpe2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)  
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1  
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.`

Comment: It's probably /dev/sdb5 or 6 (well it is on my machine anyway)

Comment: dumpe2fs /dev/sdbX -> does this command will work for NTFS partitions also? Probably that's why I get this message: Bad magic number in super-block while...